# Custom Exceptions, how much is too much?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I've been wondering how many exceptions should I have, I've seen other posts saying that it is good to have multiple exceptions it improves readability of your code and better understanding of the error if there is one.

Now I have 5 exceptions, check UserNotFoundException and AccountExpenseNotFoundException basically both exceptions are the same, but referring to different entities.

[image: Exceptions example]

Is this a bad practice?
Should I make an exception like EntityNotFound to handle this?

Comment: I assume these are checked exceptions? If clients of your API might want to treat those exceptions the same way, e.g. return a 404 from a REST endpoint, then you could make them both extend a base class EntityNotFound. Personally I wouldn't use an exception to report not finding something, I'd return an Optional.

Comment: Yes, those are checked exceptions, my idea is to have the most specified exceptions as it can be, I wasn't sure that having a lot of exceptions is a good practice, I may end up with 100 exceptions

Answer (score 1):

No, this is good. The one downside is that you end up writing something like:

```
try {
   bookkeeperthingie();
} catch (AccountExpenseAlreadyExistsException |
   AccountExpenseNotFoundException | UsernameOrPasswordInvalidException |
   Blablabla | Morebla e) {
}
```

to avoid that, make sure your exceptions follow a hierarchy. You might for example have:

```
public class BookkeepingException extends Exception {
    public BookkeepingException(String msg) { super(msg); }
    public BookkeepingException(String msg, Throwable cause) { super(msg, cause); }
}

public class AccountExpenseAlreadyExistsException extends BookkeepingException { ... }
```

and so forth. If you find it particularly plausible that a user of your API would want to catch any kind of 'bookkeeping thingie not found' exception, make that a level in the hierarchy (but that that doesn't sound right to me).

Now you could write:

```
try {
    bookkeepingthingie();
} catch (BookkeepingException e) {
}
```

if you don't particularly care about the kind of thing that went wrong, and catch a more specific one if you do, or even combine them (if not found, do this. for any other bookkeeping issue, do this - you can do that with a hierarchy; catch the more specific one first, then the general one).